# One to many relationship mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities - shop and product. One shop can have many products, but one product always has just one shop.

```
class Shop {
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="shop_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $shopId;
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="shop")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class Product {
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
     */
    private $shop;
}
```

---

When I run the website I however get the notice error that product_id is an undefined index in `vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1778`. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the DB schema for the `Product` table?

Comment: Shop has shop_id column, and Product table has product_id, and shop_id columns.

Comment: Wow.  Exact same question being asked within 30 minutes.  Wonder if there will be a third? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257869/persisting-object-with-relationship-database-not-updating

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to reference to `shopId` field in your Product entity. Also notice that you should use entity properties' names, not names of the columns in you DB table.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="shopId")
 */
private $shop;
```

P.S. For mapping issues Symfony command `doctrine:schema:validate` may be useful.

Comment: Shouldn't it reference `shop_Id` instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same errors. And I'm 100% sure id's are ok, normal queries on them work properly.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /vol/html/fooFolder/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1778`

Comment: @khernik, what do you mean "normal" queries? raw sql? And again i'll bet this notice is caused by wrong `referencedColumnName` parameter. What parameter did you use when this notice appeared?

Comment: and again did you run command `doctrine:schema:update` after changes in mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a product_id column in the shop table. I think your shop_id column name may also be causing a conflict with the referenceColumnName value. So change the shop id column name to just Id.

Then Change the referenceColumnName to just (the shops) id.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $shopId;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $shop;
```