# Persisting object with relationship, database not updating

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 2 entities with relationship `OneToMany`.

entity Question:

```
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $answers;
```

entity answer:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
 */
private $question;
```

Here I try to persist :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $question  = new Question();
            $answer = new Answer();
            $answer2 = new Answer();


            $answer->setAnswerText('Roterdam');
            $answer2->setAnswerText('Amsterdam')
                 ->SetCorrect(true);
            $question->setQuestionText('What\'s the capital of Netherlands? ');

            $question->addAnswer($answer);
            $question->addAnswer($answer2);

            $em->persist($question);
            $em->flush();
```

When I run this code everything updates in the db except the foreign key in answer table, the `question_id` is null.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got to be one of the top five most popular Doctrine 2 questions.  But I'm too lazy to look up one to link to.

Ask yourself how the answer knows to which question does it belong?  Where is the link at the object level?

```
class Question
{
    function addAnswer($answer)
    {
        $this->answers[] = $answer;
        $answer->setQuestion($this);
    }
}
```